display-buffer-alist action conditional on major mode
When opening a new buffer, I want to ensure that:

All non-inferior-ess-r-mode buffers are displayed in a new window to the left of the focus buffer
All inferior-ess-r-mode buffers are displayed in a new window to the right of the focus buffer

I have tried the following, but opening an inferior-ess-r-mode buffer still opens a new window to the left of the focus buffer
  (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '((not (major-mode . inferior-ess-r-mode))
               (display-buffer-in-direction)
               (direction . leftmost)))

    (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '((major-mode . inferior-ess-r-mode)
               (display-buffer-in-direction)
               (direction . rightmost)))

Please advise.

There are some text-book examples in the manual using a regexp for the buffer name; and, a custom function (e.g, a test for a particular major mode) can be assigned to a particular regexp (narrowly defined or a catch-all) if so desired ...  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Zen-of-Buffer-Display.html  The following thread has a complex example of a custom function assigned to regexp ...:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18346785

The solution is to simply set the value of display-buffer-alist as opposed to adding to its existing definition.
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '(((not (major-mode . inferior-ess-r-mode))
         (display-buffer-in-direction)
         (direction . leftmost))

        ((major-mode . inferior-ess-r-mode)
         (display-buffer-in-direction)
         (direction . rightmost))))


